# What webpack and other configurations should be changed after ejecting create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have created ny react app using create-react-app.  Now i have ejected it using npm run eject, i want to have different scripts for production and development build. What Should i do ?

I have no idea how to actually go ahead to solve this scenerio.